# Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be separated morphisms of schemes. Must $g\circ f:X\to Z$ be a separated morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we $\Delta_{X/Y}$ and $\Delta_{Y/Z}$ be the diagonal morphisms (both closed immersions), then I wish to show that the diagonal morphism $\Delta_{X/Z}$ is a closed immersion. Do we have any easy statement, like $\Delta_{X/Z}=\Delta_{Y/Z}\circ\Delta_{X/Y}$, or something similar, that can be used to prove this statement?

Comment: Any good property of morphisms should be stable under composition, and separatedness is one of the best. I'm too lazy to typeset the diagram right now but hopefully this is enough: there is a natural morphism $X \times_Y X \to X \times_Z X$. Show that comes from base-changing $\Delta_{Y/Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KU gives (more than) the answer to your question!